# Using Go modules with private repositories via HTTP without SSL

Tags: git, http, go, go-modules

Is there a way to force the `go` command to use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

I am trying to move a project to Go Modules, but this project includes a private `git` repository as a dependency.
This `git` repository is hosted in a private LAN behind a firewall and I usually 
clone it with something like `cd $GOPATH/git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/ && git clone http://my-user:my-password@git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame.git`.

However now the commands `go mod`, `go get` and `go test` are trying to use HTTP with SSL (HTTPS).

This setting is not helping:

```
git config \
  --global \
  url."http://my-user:my-password@git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame".insteadOf \
  "http://git.ourdomain.net"
```

(Check here for some context around `git` settings for private repositories: https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/go-modules-with-private-git-repositories-dfe795068db4)

I've amended the file `go.mod` to include a reference to that private repository (using a pattern like `git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame@v0.0.0-<YYYYMMDDHHmmSS>-<GIT_COMMIT_ID>`), but when invoking `go test` with a file `go.mod` including that private repo, then I see:

```
go: git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame@v0.0.0-<YYYYMMDDHHmmSS>-<GIT_COMMIT_ID>: unrecognized import path "git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame" (https fetch: Get https://git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame?go-get=1: dial tcp <PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS>:443: connect: connection refused)
```

I've also tried to revert `go.mod` to the original version (without that private repository) and tried to `go get` from the path where the file `go.mod` is stored, assuming that will somehow update the `go.mod` file via HTTP because of `-insecure` (check here https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_aware_go_get), like this:

```
GO111MODULE=on go get -insecure -u git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame
```

But this gave the error message:

```
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to
access it.
```

I know I should use SSL, but I've never had control on this `git` server to configure it the way it should be configured. So I just used `git clone` providing an HTTP URL (when behind the firewall) and it always worked.

Comment: [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) offers unlimited free private repositories. That would be a more featureful and secure solution.

Comment: Hehe I'll use this comment to push GitLab in front of bureaucracy :)

Answer (score 0):

The `go` command begins fetching a given module path by resolving that path to a version-control location. In order to resolve the path, it issues an HTTPS request and looks for a `<meta name="go-import" […]>` tag as described at https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths.

If you want it to skip that step, you must indicate that the import path is a raw version-control path by using a version-control suffix (listed in that same documentation).

If you write `import "git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame.git"` instead of `import "git.ourdomain.net/foo/bar/reponame"`, you should find that the initial HTTPS resolution is skipped and the subsequent `git` operation uses the `insteadOf` declaration from your global `git` configuration.